# How to order array items by date format YYYY MM DD in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

My array format is the following:

```
array(4) {
  ["2014-12-13"]=> string(6) "432564"
  ["2014-12-12"]=> int(0)
  ["2014-12-14"]=> int(0)
  ["2014-12-15"]=> int(0)
}
```

And I would like to get the following result:

```
array(4) {
  ["2014-12-12"]=> int(0)
  ["2014-12-13"]=> string(6) "432564"
  ["2014-12-14"]=> int(0)
  ["2014-12-15"]=> int(0)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use [ksort()](http://php.net/ksort) function:

```
ksort($arraywithDateKeys);
```

Comment: $array= ksort($array);
        var_dump($array);
It returns TRUE.

Comment: You don't need to assign  
$array=  ksort($array); because ksort takes variable by reference. Do: ksort($array); var_dump($array);

Comment: Ooops, that was the problem, thank you!